# HTTP over Bluetooth

Tags: http, https, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does the HTTP Proxy service of Bluetooth let me treat a BLE device as if it were an HTTP server, e.g. so that an app that talks to the device can send it GET/POST/PUT requests?

Or does this operate is the opposite direction, where the BLE device sends GET/POST/PUT through an app to a faraway server?

Answer (score 3):

Your second paragraph is the intended usage. The peripheral sends a request to some central device, which acts as a proxy and forwards the request to a faraway server.

But you could of course do it the other way around, but in that case you need to define a hostname so you can form a proper URI.

Note that the spec can only handle 512 bytes of data.